# At the police station, why does Kyle Reese ends up having to punch a door to save Sarah?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

At the police station, Kyle Reese punching a door was a bad move on his part, as it could've given them away. Why did he resort to such extreme measures?

Answer (score 2):

Because the door was locked and he was in an extreme hurry, given that the Terminator is clearly attacking the building and methodically checking each room.

Getting to Sarah (so that he can start getting her out of harm's way) is his only priority. The longer he waits, the closer the Terminator gets and that includes going off to find something to bust the window with.

> Sarah jumped as a loud rattle broke the new silence. It was the
> doorknob. Someone was trying to get in. Her teeth were chattering with
> fear as she peered over the top of the desk. A large silhouette was
> visible just beyond the opaque glass door. It was him. She knew it.
>
> Sarah ducked back under the desk. Raw terror was creeping over her.
> These were to be the last moments of her life. There was a loud crash
> of glass. Someone punched through the door’s window and reached inside
> for the lock.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Terminator - Official Novelisation](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/The_Terminator_(Frakes_novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: Valorum: So in that sense, it was better to do something and make a noise than not do anything at all and waste time. I get it now.